# Resources for annotated or commented games by level of audience

Tags: learning, online, annotation

Similar questions have been asked before [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/9237/good-resource-for-annotated-games) or [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/9573/commented-games-for-beginners). Still I think it would be more useful to have these resources listed by level. There is not much point for a beginner to listen to a GM explaining long lines and deep positional ideas. Similarly an advanced player does not want to learn about how the knight moves. So the question is:

What are freely available resources for annotated or commented games and in what category of audience would you put them?

I am looking for:

- written and audio and video
- names of players/streamers...
- names of concrete events (e.g. banter blitz with ..., commentary on tournament... by ...)
- can overlap levels but preferrably not cover more than two levels

So just saying chess24 is not enough as that includes a whole range of levels.

For the levels I suggest the chess.com system (but am open to alternatives) In any case that would be just a rough guideline:

- beginner <1400
- intermediate  1400 - 2000
- expert 2000 - 2200
- Master 2200+

Answer (score 1):

[Hanging Pawns has quite a few videos that annotate GM games, and I'd say they're probably intermediate to maybe expert (using your format)](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCkJdvwRC-oGPhRHW_XPNokg)

[Agadmator has a ton of videos annotating GM games (often released mere hours after the game finishes!) I'd say probably beginner-intermediate on your scale.](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCL5YbN5WLFD8dLIegT5QAbA)
Note that both of these channels annotate after the game, not during.